# SwiftUI: ViewModifier together with id() on a cell causes ScrollView performance issues

Tags: performance, swiftui, scrollview, viewmodifier, lazyvstack

There is very poor performance when pulling scroll bar indicator to bottom and scrolling cells with big ordinal numbers. But if we comment empty ViewModifier applied to cell, everything became ok.

This code is simplified example of real case, when number of items is big and we need an ability to recover scroll position to certain item (thats why we need id() and ScrollViewReader). So is it mean we are unable to use any ViewModifiers for cells?

```
final class ItemList { }

extension ItemList {
    
    struct Ui : View {
        
        @StateObject private var viewModel: ViewModel
        
        init() { self._viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: ViewModel()) }
        
        var body: some View {
            ScrollView { ScrollViewReader { _ in
                LazyVStack { ForEach(Array(viewModel.items.enumerated()), id: \.offset) {
                    Cell($0.offset)
                        .modifier(EmptyModifier()) // <- without one of these lines scroll performance is ok
                        .id($0.offset)             // <- without one of these lines scroll performance is ok
                } }.padding([.leading, .trailing])
            } }
        }
        
    }
    
    private struct Cell : View {
        
        private let index: Int
        
        init(_ index: Int) { self.index = index }
        
        var body: some View {
            HStack { Spacer(); Text("\(index)"); Spacer() }
                .padding()
                .background(Color.gray)
                .cornerRadius(8)
        }
        
    }
    
    private final class ViewModel : ObservableObject {
        
        let items: [String] = .init(repeating: "item", count: 200000)
        
    }
    
}

private struct EmptyModifier : ViewModifier {
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View { content }
    
}
```

Comment: I'd imagine this combination makes the attribute graph complicated enough that SwiftUI can't deal with in a reasonable amount of time. That said, why are you using `id` in the first place? `ForEach` already has `id: \.offset`. Also, can you use `tag` instead of `id`?

Comment: `scrollViewProxy` requires an `id` for recovering scroll position with `scrollTo(_ id: ID, anchor: UnitPoint?)`, thats why i'm using id here

Comment: `ForEach` *already* gives your views an id, that is the same the keypath you passed to its `id:` argument. You don't need an explicit id here, in any case.

Comment: There are a couple of big mistakes: in SwiftUI the `View` struct is the view model you shouldn't have a `@StateObject` view model. `ForEach` needs to be supplied an array of `Identifiable` model data it can't be used with indices.